# Stopping UDP Attack

Tags: udp, attacks

I am now getting support emails from OVH that there is unusual activity on my server.

This is a simple server that I have RDP connections for students to access QuickBooks, Excel, and Word, and there is nothing else on the server, and I have group policies set that they have almost no access to anything including the internet, files, etc ...

The below is the message I am getting for OVH ... I have blocked all UDP outbound in the windows firewall and the computer configuration ... I am not an expert in this area ... will this stop the unusual behavior.

```
Attack detail : 4Kpps/53Mbps
dateTime srcIp:srcPort dstIp:dstPort protocol flags packets bytes reason
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 67.220.81.64:15800 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 67.220.81.64:703 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 201.71.201.195:41519 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 67.220.81.64:19103 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 72.204.176.88:8080 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 67.220.81.64:11396 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 24.217.44.95:80 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 72.204.176.88:8080 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 67.220.81.64:32431 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 67.220.81.64:48208 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 67.220.81.64:7814 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 201.71.202.157:61154 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 87.123.195.143:443 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 67.220.81.64:22084 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 67.220.81.64:34101 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 67.220.81.64:32807 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 67.220.81.64:60109 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 67.220.81.64:38144 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 67.220.81.64:27707 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
2021.08.15 21:56:26 CEST 135.148.34.13:389 67.220.81.64:28195 UDP --- 16384 24870912 ATTACK:UDP
```

Comment: Check what you've got on 389 and see its logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is being used in a LDAP amplification DDoS attack. (Port 389)

Make sure your LDAP server is not publicly accessible!

Comment: I googled how to stop a LDAP amplification attack and it seemed simple ... disable the Active Directory Domain Controller - LDAP (UDP-In) inbound firewall rule and also Active Directory Domain Controller - LDAP (TCP-In) and Active Directory Domain Controller - Secure LDAP (TCP-In) rules ...

Is that it ?

Thanks